# PHP convert datetime to seconds

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a datetime value in `mysql` '2010-12-08 16:12:12'
that I'd like to get the seconds to that date using `PHP`,
so basically a `PHP` equivalent of `mysql` :

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2010-12-08 16:12:12',now()))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

huh ? these function are from `mysql` ...

For PHP, you replace it using `strtotime`

```
$diff = strtotime('2010-12-08 16:12:12')-time();
```

details : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: It is not true, because `time()` is greater than old timestamp row from DB

Answer (score 27):

```
<?php

$date1 = new DateTime("2010-12-08 16:12:12");
$now = new DateTime();

$difference_in_seconds = $date1->format('U') - $now->format('U');
```

`->format('U')` turns it into a unix timestamp.

Comment: $date->getTimestamp() might be a bit better @notJim http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: THANK YOU! This ('U') format is actually very useful!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$time_diff = time() - strtotime('2010-12-08 16:12:12');
```

Answer (score -2):

Use mktime()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: mktime() doesn't convert MySQL format dates (2010-12-08 16:12:12)