# Percentual between two DateTime Objects

Tags: php, datetime, math, logic

This is NOT homework and I'll need some time to explain.

---

Everytime I need to find how much percent of **X** a **Y** value represents, I use this formula:

```
D = BC / A
```

Which is a contracted version of what we've learned in school:

```
A --- B
C --- C
```

Being:

- **A** the value I know and represents 100% of the amount
- **B** how much of the whole **A** represents (always 100)
- **C** the value I know and represents **X%** of the amount
- **D** the **X%** I want to know

For example:

*In a basket with 10 apples, 6 of them are good to eat. How many apples, in percent, should go to the trash?*

```
D = BC / A
D = ( 100 * 6 ) / 10
D = 60%
```

In this example **D** represents the number of good apples (6) so the other 40% (4) should go to the trash. :D

All good? Let me continue.

But what about time? Consider this scenario:

*A running test (like marathon) has a time limit of 10 minutes. If a runner finishes the test in 5 minutes, how fast he was, relative to the total time?*

The answer is clearly **50%** but when using the schema above in the code below, I'm not receiving this result.

The first thing I did was create both DateTime Objects and format them to seconds using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392077/753531) I've found here:

```
$total      = "00:10:00";
$running    = "00:05:00";

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $total );
$dt1f = $dt1 -> format( 'U' ); // 1415067000

$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $running );
$dt2f = $dt2 -> format( 'U' ); // 1415066700
```

And then I filled the variables in the (contracted) formula:

```
$x = ( ( 100 * $dtf2 ) / $dtf1 ); // 99.99997879959
```

First I thought it could be a problem with the DateTime formatting so I faked the day, month and year throwing them to January 1st, 1970 and thus getting smaller values:

```
$total      = "1970-01-01 00:10:00";
$running    = "1970-01-01 00:05:00";

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $total );
$dt1f = $dt1 -> format( 'U' ); // 11400

$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $running );
$dt2f = $dt2 -> format( 'U' ); // 11100
```

But instead of receive the smaller and correct value, now **$x** resulted in *97.368421052632* o.O

I tested the resulting *timestamps* with date() just in case to be sure they were representing, respectively 10 and 5 minutes and they are fine.

Although the math is correct (I ran in the calculator), the logic is not computing as I would expect.

Any clues?

Comment: what about if you convert all in seconds : 10mn => 600s, 5mn => 300s. (300/600)*100 = 50 '%' ?

Comment: PHP: `$x = ( ( 100 * 11100 ) / 11400 );` => 97.368421052632 ; SQL: `select ( ( 100 * 11100 ) / 11400 );` => 97.  Why?  PHP is just squirly on numbers?

Comment: @developerwjk Int divided by int is int in SQL. :)

Comment: @DarkAvanger , Exactly. So the question ultimately is "How can I get PHP to divide INT as INT like a strongly typed language?"

Comment: @developerwjk No, I think the question is about operating on right time intervals. The OP is comparing wrong values. The Funk Doc and Halayem Anis answered the question already, I suppose.

Comment: Just in case: `$x = intval( intval( 100 * $dtf2 ) / intval($dtf1) );` will treat as int throughout.

Comment: This might sound a little harsh but... Did you understand the question or you are just throwing random hypothesis completely not related with the case exposed? @JonathanKuhn understood it, and solved 99% of the problem in one shot. Precise like a sniper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the second (epoch adjusted code) is your zero time is adjusted for timezone. If you were to check the time for `1-1-1970 00:00:00` it wouldn't return the timestamp `0` but whatever your timezone offset is in seconds. You can see this by looking at your timestamps. 10 minutes is 600 seconds (10 * 60), not 11400 seconds (which would be 3 hours 10 minutes so I'm assuming the server is set to a +3 timezone). You need to get the `00:00:00` value and subtract that from both of your numbers first to get the elapsed and duration time.

And for the full datetime, you have a similar issue. You are assuming that `0` is today at `00:00:00` but really it is unix epoch (+/- timezone). So you are looking at 300 seconds between the two numbers compared to 44 years of seconds. Which would equal about 99.999...% of the way through.

[Example (click to see result)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KTcAYW):

```
<?php
$start      = "00:00:00";
$total      = "00:10:00";
$running    = "00:05:00";

$dt0 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $start );
$dt0f = $dt0 -> format( 'U' );

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $total );
$dt1f = $dt1 -> format( 'U' );

$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i:s', $running );
$dt2f = $dt2 -> format( 'U' );

//get the duration of time from start to end
$duration = $dt1f - $dt0f;
//get the elapsed amount of time from the start to running
$elapsed = $dt2f - $dt0f;

$pct = ((100 * $elapsed) / $duration);

//outputs: 50
var_dump($pct);
```

[adjusted for unix epoch (click to see result)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JVhNGP) (same output):

```
<?php
$start      = "1970-01-01 00:00:00";
$total      = "1970-01-01 00:10:00";
$running    = "1970-01-01 00:05:00";

$dt0 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $start );
$dt0f = $dt0 -> format( 'U' );

$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $total );
$dt1f = $dt1 -> format( 'U' );

$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $running );
$dt2f = $dt2 -> format( 'U' );

//get the duration of time from start to end
$duration = $dt1f - $dt0f;
//get the elapsed amount of time from the start to running
$elapsed = $dt2f - $dt0f;

$pct = ((100 * $elapsed) / $duration);

var_dump($pct);
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! One last question: Could this be solved without computing your **$start**? Perhaps... By using a DateTimeZone in *DateTime::createFromFormat()*?

Comment: You could set a timezone of GMT which has a timezone offset of 0 and then do your math based off unix epoch like your second example.

Comment: I thought so but, before the last comment I tried that, using a DateTimeZone object with **UTC** and **GMT0**, which I confirmed with *DateTimeZone::getOffset()* but I received the same 99%, just like if I hadn't used them. Somehow, seems the *date_default_timezone_set()* used to get rid of that startup Warning is being taken in consideration regardless what DateTime is instructed to.

Comment: Are you also using the date `1-1-1970`? You would have to include that for it to be right along with the timezone.

Comment: That's right! Using the... "full", unix epoch format the DateTimeZone worked as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

convert to minutes?

```
$total      = "01:10:00";
$running    = "00:45:12";
function timesPercentDiff($ts1,$ts2) 
{ 
list($hours1, $minutes1,$seconds1) = explode(':', $ts1); 
list($hours2, $minutes2,$seconds2) = explode(':', $ts2);
$min1=$hours1 * 60 + $minutes1 + $seconds1/60; 
$min2=$hours2 * 60 + $minutes2 + $seconds2/60;
return $min2/$min1*100;
} 
echo  timesPercentDiff($total,$running);
```

Comment: This would work until you hit daylight savings and `hours * 60` is really +/- an hour from what that returns.

Comment: Not everyone uses DST so in an area that does modifications would need to be made. Ideally the modification being local govt getting rid of the rediculous DST system.

Comment: Yes, but getting the gov't to change is harder than changing your code to work within the dst system.

Comment: Depends on your definition of hard I suppose.

Comment: Benjamin Franklin is revolving in his tomb right now... But your approach has another problem: It's using a hammer in a screw. DateTime is not perfect. It has several obscure bugs related to problems so specific that only a few persons use and hardly report as bug. However it was designed to manipulate date and time (and their derivations) and all programmers must be conscientized to use it instead of embrace the first valid workaround.

Comment: @vascowhite My comment about DST is that in a place that observes DST, on a date when the change happens and when the time is after the 2am change, the amount of time passed will not be correct.The number of hours passed since midnight hours * 60 will be +/- 60 minutes based off the change since an hour has been repeated or skipped. For example, this year on Nov 2 which was DST change in the US, at 4am, 5 hours has actually passed since midnight: 1am, 1am (as of 2am time goes back an hour), 2am, 3am and 4am. However 4*60 only counts 4 hours. I bumped into this with a poorly made gantt chart.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn If you measure two hours on a stop watch it is two hours regardless of any time change. DST only becomes an issue when you confuse date times with the measurement of a time period. However, you are correct this answer does fall foul of the DST pitfall.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not terribly familiar with PHP or the PHP DateTime object, but using your formula from above:

D = BC / A

$A = $dt1::getTimeStamp();

$B = 100;

$C = $dt2::getTimeStamp();

$D = ($B * $C) / $A;

Comment: Plausible, because this method would do the same as formatting the object as Unix Epoch, but it wouldn't solve the timezone issue anyway.